# How do I filter the child entities within a parent entity based on child properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I currently have entities titled Job (the parent entity) and Attachment (the child entity, with a none-to-many relationship). The Attachment entity has a boolean property titled IsDeleted so that I can use that to "delete" data as far as the user is concerned, but actually, leave it intact on the database. Of course, this means I need to make sure that my queries are excluding the correct child entities.

I cannot figure out how to use .Include to get most of the attachments, but deliberately exclude the ones for which IsDeleted == true

The models for those entities are as follows:

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}
public class Attachment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

How do I query the Jobs entity on the database context such that it will include all of the Attachments, but NOT the ones for which IsDeleted == true?

For example, if I use the following query (where I know 16 is the id of the record I need):

```
var tmpJob = context.Jobs
    .Include(j => j.Attachments)
    .Where(j => j.Id == 16)
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

This gives me all the attachments, including the deleted ones.

But I can't seem to do something like
        .Include(j => j.Attachments.Where(a => a.IsDeleted == false)
as that simply doesn't work.

I even considered a workaround to manually remove the items, such as the following:

```
    var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    foreach (var attachment in tmpJob.Attachments)
    {
        if (!attachment.IsDeleted)
            attachments.Add(attachment);
    }
    tmpJob.Attachments = attachments;
```

Unfortunately, if I do that, and if later I make changes to the tmpJob entity (and perform a context.SaveChanges on it), then it completely removes the FK relationship between the Job and Attachment, so that won't work either.

I thought I saw somewhere that what I'm wanting isn't (currently) supported in Entity Framework (2.1 is the version I'm using), but even if that's the case, I'm at a loss to figure out even an acceptable workaround.

Comment: How about utilizing [global query filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#model-level-query-filters)? Your scenario is one of the targeted usage cases of that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using  `Any()` to achieve that conditional:

```
var tmpJob = context.Jobs
.Include(j => j.Attachments)
.Where(j => j.Id == 16 && j.Attachments.Any(a => a.IsDeleted == false))
.FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: I tried that @jcvegan, and the entity it's returning still has all attachments (including the ones where IsDeleted == true).

I'm not sure what I'm missing.